Salesforce LiveChatTranscriptEvent trigger is not working when there is a new message
I am trying to implement a custom LWC for new message event using platform events. In order to do that, I am trying to trigger an event using the trigger but the Trigger is not triggered when there is new message.
here is my trigger:
trigger LiveChatTranscriptEventTrigger on LiveChatTranscriptEvent (after insert) {
    List<NewChatMessage__e> events = new List<NewChatMessage__e>();

    for (LiveChatTranscriptEvent event : Trigger.new) {
        system.debug('NEW MESSAGE: ' + event.Type + '>>' +event.Detail);
        if (event.Type == 'ChatMessage') {
            String messageContent = 'New message in chat transcript: ' + event.LiveChatTranscriptId;
            
            events.add(new NewChatMessage__e(
                TranscriptId__c = event.LiveChatTranscriptId,
                Message__c = messageContent
            ));
        }
    }

    if (!events.isEmpty()) {
        EventBus.publish(events);
    }
}

If its not possible, can anyone suggest a better way to implement it?

As per the article,


LiveChatTranscriptEvent records are created at the end of the chat on the final upsertion of the LiveChatTranscript record (when
the chat ends and the Chat tab is closed).
All the LiveChatTranscriptEvent records are inserted in a single transaction but one by one, i.e. the Trigger is executed for an
individual record at a time.
  trigger LCTE on LiveChatTranscriptEvent (before insert) {
    // Trigger.New will have only 1 record at a time and trigger will 
    execute for individual record
    for(LiveChatTranscriptEvent l : Trigger.New)
      system.debug(l.Type + '>>' +l.Detail);
  }    




Update[09/09/2024]:
Instead of relying on LiveChatTranscriptEvent, you can use the LiveChatTranscript object to capture new messages. You can create a trigger on the LiveChatTranscript object to publish platform events when new messages are added.
trigger LiveChatTranscriptTrigger on LiveChatTranscript (after insert, after update) {
        List<NewChatMessage__e> events = new List<NewChatMessage__e>();

        for (LiveChatTranscript transcript : Trigger.new) {
                if (transcript.LastModifiedDate != Trigger.oldMap.get(transcript.Id).LastModifiedDate) {
                        String messageContent = 'New message in chat transcript: ' + transcript.Id;

                        events.add(new NewChatMessage__e(
                                TranscriptId__c = transcript.Id,
                                Message__c = messageContent
                        ));
                }
        }

        if (events.size() > 0) {
                EventBus.publish(events);
        }
}


Thanks for your response Tusher, is there any way to call the trigger or the LWC when receive a new message?

@KarthikSekar, I have updated the answer. Please have a look.

Hi @tushar-jadav, I've tried using a simple trigger with logging enabled, but I can't see any logs in the developer tool under 'Log' or 'Raw Log'. I also created traces for both the trigger and automation, but there are still no logs related to my trigger. However, I am able to see logs for my test Account update trigger.
trigger myLiveChatTranscriptTrigger on LiveChatTranscript (after insert, after update) {
System.debug('Triggered => myLiveChatTranscriptTrigger');
}
